# Using IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I'm using IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML in google sheets and I've managed to have some success scraping financial data points from yahoo, reuters and finviz but I'm having an issue scraping data from a couple sites where I thought it would be easier based on how the data is shown.

I'm specifically trying to scrape the 5yr Avg P/E from here: https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/nvda/valuation, it's in the same spot of the page no matter what stock I'm looking at and it's in a table, so I started using IMPORTHTML but it's having trouble picking up the table data, I keep getting an 'N/A' output. Then I thought I would use IMPORTXML and it would be easy enough to use the 'copy XPath' function- wrong.

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/nvda/valuation","table",1),4,13)

=IMPORTXML("https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/nvda/valuation", "//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/sal-components/section/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[13]/span")
```

**note**- I've also tried changing the table number in the html fx and removing the '/tbody' from my formula in the xml fx per other message boards but I continue to get an 'ERROR' output.

I'm going in circles here, so any direction is appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: many sites go to great lengths to prevent you from scraping as it undermines their advertising business model.  I would check out the free API at tenquant.io  .easily grabbable csvs for using the =IMPORTDATA() function.

Comment: thanks Matt- yes, I was concerned that might be an issue- nothing is free.  I'll look into tenquant.io if this doesn't pan out.  thanks for bringing to my attention.